# Initialize generic templated container

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, operator-overloading

I'm trying to write a general container (called 'tcontainer_t') that it's inner implementation could use vector or list, and a T type, according to the user's will. Problem arise when in main, when I try to create a 'tcontainer_t' object  - no one knows before run time if the container type is vector or list.

```
//tcontainer_t.h

#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

template <class T, class Container >
class tContainer_t {
private:
    Container container;
    typedef typename Container::iterator iter_t;
    iter_t it;

public:
    tContainer_t();
    tContainer_t<T, Container>(const tContainer_t<T, Container>& other);
    tContainer_t<T, Container>& operator=(const tContainer_t<T, Container>& classObj);
    virtual ~tContainer_t();

};

#endif /* TCONTAINERT_H_ */
```

the cpp file is:

```
 // tContainert.cpp

#include "tContainer_t.h"

//  default constructor
template < class T, class Container >
tContainer_t<T, Container>::tContainer_t() {

    this->container = new Container;   //C2679 binary '=' no operator found which takes...

}

//   copy constructor
template < class T, class Container >
tContainer_t<T, Container>::tContainer_t(const tContainer_t<T, Container>& other) {


}

//operator "="
template < class T, class Container >
tContainer_t<T, Container>& tContainer_t<T, Container>::operator=(const tContainer_t<T, Container>& classObj) {
    if (this != &classObj){
   }
    return *this;
}


template < class T, class Container >
tContainer_t<T, Container>::~tContainer_t() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
```

and main is:

```
    int main() {

    tContainer_t<int, vector<int*> > vContainer;

    return 0;
}
```

please ignore destructor and operator "=" - both exist, I eliminated the code to clarify my question.
Compilation Error pops at this line:

```
this->container = new Container;
```

And I know it's not the right way to do it.

but how can I instantiate vector or list using this? what should be written in the constructor?

Thanks!

Comment: You're a Java programmer, right?

Comment: Seriously, what is the goal of this class? What real problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Believe me I wouldn't invent myself such a bad design. It's an assignment I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a default-constructed container, you don't need to write anything at all; the compiler does that for you.

If you want to initzialize the container to something different, you use a constructor initializer. For example, let's assume `Container` has a constructor taking an initial size (as the standard containers have), then you could write

```
template<class T, class Container>
 tContainer_t<T, Container>::tContainer_t():
  container(25) // make a container with 25 elements
{
}
```

Note that in C++, unlike e.g. in Java, the member variable `container` is an actual object of type `Container`, not just a reference to one. `new Container` created one on the heap and returns a *pointer* to that. So what you are trying to do is to assign a pointer to `Container` to a `Container`, which fails because `Container` has no constructor taking a pointer to `Container`.

Note that if you were to dereference the pointer returned by `new`, it would compile (assuming `Container` is copyable, which for standard containers just means the contained type is), but still not do what you intend: It would create a Container object on the heap, assign it to the `container` member (which means *copying* all the content into the object `container`), and then you'd be left with a memory leak because the pointer returned by `new` is temporary and nowhere assigned, and especially not deleted.

Comment: You should also point out that he was trying to assign a vector<int*>* to a vector<int*>, hence the compiler error. You know, just to clarify what he did wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, I feel compelled to point out the following.

> Scott Meyers, Effective STL
>
> **Item 2: Beware the illusion of container-independent code**
>
> The STL is based on generalization. Arrays are generalized into
>   containers and parameterized on the types of objects they contain.
>   Functions are generalized into algorithms and parameterized on the
>   types of iterators they use. Pointers are generalized into iterators
>   and parameterized on the type of objects they point to.
>
> That’s just the beginning. Individual container types are generalized
>   into sequence and associative containers, and similar containers are
>   given similar functionality. Standard contiguous-memory containers
>   (see Item 1) offer random-access iterators, while standard node-based
>   containers (again, see Item 1) provide bidirectional iterators.
>   Sequence containers support push_front and/or push_back, while
>   associative containers don’t. Associative containers offer
>   logarithmic-time lower_bound, upper_bound, and equal_range member
>   functions, but sequence containers don’t.
>
> http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/cplusplus/9780321545183/containers/ch01lev1sec2

The class template

```
template <class T, class Container >
class tContainer_t {
```

have `T` and `Container` as separate independent template parameters. Doesn't that defeat the goal as we see in the following usage?

```
tContainer_t<int, vector<int*> > vContainer;
```

`int` and `int *` are quite different.